# Nginx Cors Angular9 RestApi

Tags: angular, nginx, cors

i'm an angular beginner and try to deploy a CRUD app. I found this [src](https://morioh.com/p/f1b8d68905a6), compile successfully, upload on my vps but when i check on browser i've got a Cors error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/api. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

I installed nginx server and setup
/etc/nginx/sites-available/mySite.com :

```
server{
 listen 80;
 listen [::]:80;

 root /var/www/mySite.com/html;
 server_name xxx.xx.xxx.xxx;

 location /{
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
  try_files $uri /index.html;
 }

}
```

I put the site code in /var/www/mySite/html, with a proxy [config](https://www.positronx.io/handle-cors-in-angular-with-proxy-configuration/) and the server code in /var/www/mySite/api, where i call cors lib:

```
        var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cors = require('cors');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var casesRouter = require('./routes/cases');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/coronavirus', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB!');
});

var app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/api', casesRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

..here's the a screenshot of Firefox (68.8.0esr) network tab :

[image]

..and a Chromium screenshot:

[image]

Cors setup in Nginx and RestApi have no effect.
Any idea ?

thanks

ps: i use npm (v6.14.4), node(v13.12.0), nginx (1.14)

Answer (score 0):

in node app you can do next thing:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const requestedHeaders = req.header('Access-Control-Request-Headers');
  const parsedHeaders = [];
  if (typeof requestedHeaders === 'string') {
    parsedHeaders.push(...requestedHeaders.toLowerCase().split(','));
  }
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
  // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  if (parsedHeaders.length) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', parsedHeaders.join(', '));
  }
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
  next();
});
```

instead of or right after

```
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Thank's for suggestion but i still have the same Cors error :/

Comment: Might you share a screenshot from network tab of the failed request with request and response headers?

Comment: I've updated my post with network tab and console return, merci..

Comment: Sorry, it's updated. We can see on Header response that "Access-Control-Allow-Origin 
*" is allowed ... In other hand i have to resolve an error 502 about favicon.ico loading...

Comment: But there's no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on the screenshot, where do you see it?

Comment: I updated the screencapture in my post above, the 1st selected line of FilterURLs return "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"or just have a look here: http://145.14.158.230

Comment: it sends a request to `http://localhost:3000/api`, no to a remove API, nevertheless when I created a simple express app and used the above above it works. I can see the request has been passed. Here is a screencast: https://take.ms/OGaNB

Comment: You meant you used my api code and it work ? ([Here's the complete code: [link]https://github.com/didinj/coronavirus-restapi[/link]) I added to my post a screen capture of Chromium where we can see the failed request http://localhost:3000/api.

Comment: Yep, I meant I created an express app, added in index.js the core from your question and the code from my answer and run it on localhost:3000/api, then I opened 145.14.158.230 in my browser and didn't get CORS error, once I've removed the code from my answer the request fails.

Comment: Cool, checking your API.

Comment: I tested in safari and chrome. Then it should work too. Do you have a screenshot with the headers and the error? Perhaps some other request causes the issue.